# TypeError: this.getISO is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I getting typeerror: this.getISO is not a function.

I am trying to implement mapbox API with 3 isochrones plot on it. but i am getting an error that this.getISO is not a function.

```js
map.on("load", function() {
      map.addSource("iso", {
        type: "geojson",
        data: {
          type: "FeatureCollection",
          features: []
        }
      });

      map.addLayer(
        {
          id: "isoLayer",
          type: "fill",
          // Use "iso" as the data source for this layer
          source: "iso",
          layout: {},
          paint: {
            // The fill color for the layer is set to a light purple
            "fill-color": "#5a3fc0",
            "fill-opacity": 0.3
          }
        },
        "poi-label"
      );
      this.getISO(data => {
        map.getSource("iso").setData(data);
      });
    });
    this.map = map;
  }

  getISO(callback) {
    const { duration, lng, lat } = this.state;
    fetch(
      `https://api.mapbox.com/isochrone/v1/mapbox/driving/${lng},${lat}?
        contours_minutes=${duration}&polygons=true&
        access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoiam9uYnN0b3JleSIsImEiOiJjanl5aGFyaWwxaGE3M21ycnhsNGpvYmk2In0.jfxHlg5boDqdiUgf3cco2A`
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        callback(data);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Have you binded getISO function in constructor?
```constructor( props ){
    super( props );
    this.getISO = this.getISO.bind(this);  }```

Comment: I did it now. Issue Resolved Thanks

Comment: So maybe you can vote on the answer? ;)

Answer (score 1):

in first-line replace function definition with arrow function and the

like this `map.on("load", ()=> {`

Answer (score 1):

Use an arrow function `() => {` instead of `function() {`.